# Ideal of whole numbers generates whole ring, can we find a linear combination of 1 with coefficients always whole numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a unitary ring. For $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can embed $a,b$ in $R$. Now consider the ideal $I:=(a,b)$ in $R$. If $(a,b )= R$ we find $c,d\in R$ such that $ac+bd = 1$. Can we always chose $c,d$ such that they come from the embeding of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not really.  Consider $R=\mathbb R$ and $I=(2,2)$.  Then $2\cdot\frac12+2\cdot 0=1$, but you'll never be able to do it with integers.

It's because the abelian subgroup generated by $2$ can't ever escape the multiples of $2$.  Being able to multiply by other elements of the ring to produce elements in the ideal expands it considerably.

Comment: Can we chose the elements always of the center of the ring?

Comment: You would have to rephrase your problem quite a bit to make it suitable for a noncommutative ring.

Comment: Shouldnt it be a problem since $a,b$ will be always in the center of the ring?

Comment: Wait: you're right. If you just ask $c,d$ to be central, then you may as well consider the commutative subring generated by $a,b,c,d$, which, as we've seen, need not allow integer solutions $c,d$.

Comment: But can always chose $c,d$ to be central?

Comment: sry for the misunderstanding. What i mean is: for a unitary ring $R$ (possibly non commutative). if $a,b$ are integers and $(a,b) = R$. Then can we always find $c,d$ in the center of $R$ such that $ac+bd =1 $?

Comment: but isnt $1/2$ in the center of $A$?

Comment: @kevkev1695 Oh right, I'm allowed to use more than integers.  I was on the wrong page. Let me think about it some more...

Comment: @kevkev1695 Try this quotient of a free algebra: $R=\mathbb Z\langle x,y,z\rangle/(2x-z, 2y+z-1)$. In this ring, $2x+2y=1$, but I don't think you can find any central solutions to get a linear combination that's $1$. I *think* the center is just $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: yeah, that seems good. thanks!